# Finding the functions for circular reflection and their inverted forms

Tags: functions

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Show that the transformation of inversion in the unit circle is given
>   analytically by the equations $$x'=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, y'=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$Find the inverse transformation and prove
>   analytically that inversion transforms the totality of lines and
>   circles into lines and circles.

I know that the image of a point $P$ is defined to be the point $P'$ lying on the line $OP$ (where $O$ is the center of a unit circle) on the same side of $O$ and $P$ and such that $OP\cdot OP'=r^2$; which, with our circle, would mean $OP\cdot OP'=1$. Based on this information, how do I figure out what a function might look like? Obviously it has to correspond to $x'$ and $y'$, but I can't see how.

In terms of figuring out the inverse function, all I can get to is:

$$
x^2x'+y^2x' = x \\
y^2x'=x(1-xx')
$$

Is there a way of neatly factoring to get $x$ and thus inverting the function?

Comment: For finding the inverse function, note that the criterion for "the image of $P$ is $P'$" is symmetric in $P$ and $P'$ -- that is, inversion in a circle is its own inverse!

Comment: @HenningMakholm so would the inverse function of $x'$ be $x=\frac{x'}{x'^2+y'^2}$? Should it be $y^2$ or $y'^2$?

Comment: x @hohner: Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\vec{OP'}=\lambda \vec{OP}$, as $P$ and $P'$ are aligned. Then $OP\cdot OP'=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot\lambda\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$, giving the value of $\lambda$.
2. The inversion is its auto-inverse, as

$$\frac{\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}{\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2}=x.$$

3. Plugging the transformed coordinates in the implicit equation of a circle,
   $$\left(\frac x{x^2+y^2}-x_c\right)^2+\left(\frac y{x^2+y^2}-y_c\right)^2=r^2$$
   we get
   $$x^2-2x_cx(x^2+y^2)+x_c^2(x^2+y^2)^2+y^2-2y_cy(x^2+y^2)+y_c^2(x^2+y^2)^2=r^2(x^2+y^2)^2$$
   which can be simplified by $x^2+y^2$
   $$1-2x_cx+x_c^2(x^2+y^2)-2y_cy+y_c^2(x^2+y^2)=r^2(x^2+y^2),$$

which is also the equation of a circle. In the event that $x_c^2+y_c^2=r^2$, the circle degenerates to a straight line.

Comment: Won't $\lambda$ equal $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ rather than $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @hohner: Yes, it will. Remember that $(x',y')=\lambda(x,y)$, so the numerator comes from this multiplication.

Comment: No, my question was not about substituting in the numerator. I still don't understand _how_ you arrive at $x'=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ in the first place.

Comment: @hohner: $(x',y')=\lambda(x,y)$ and $\lambda=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$, so $x'=\lambda x=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}x=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @hohner: I think this discussion doesn't belong here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm How does $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm just trying to understand how you get $x'=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, y'=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ in the first place. How you derive these formulae?

Comment: It's all in the first two sentences. Evaluate $\lambda$, then $\vec{OP'}$.

Comment: @hohner: Who says that? I'm saying that $\frac1{x^2+y^2}x=\frac x{x^2+y^2}$.